# Как в реакте делать кастомные компоненты?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть кастомный селект сделанный на реакте([рабочий пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-47jbd?file=/src/App.js:457-484)) в коде подключается так:
`<Select items={elements} />` , где `elements` - массив объектов значений.

По сути все работает как надо, но есть одно "но" как мне передавать и вызывать функцию которая будет забирать значение из этого селекта ?
например: `<Select items={elements} onChange={myAwesomeChangeFunction} />` 
прокинуть функцию в компонент, с этим нет проблем, а вот как ее там обработать...

Мне просто не очень понятно как это делается в таких библиотеках как [ant design](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce)
Хочется понять как делаются такие кастомные компоненты?

**update** нужного функционала добился с использование хука `useRef()` [обновленный рабочий пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-47jbd?file=/src/App.js)

*ps: только недавно начал учить реакт :)*

Comment: В каком смысле обработать? Пишешь функцию и потом присваиваешь эту функцию в атрибут `onChange` что непонятно то?

Comment: если я пишу так: 
`<input className="Select__value-input"
            readOnly
            onChange={() => {
              props.getValue(currentValue);
            }}
            autoComplete="off"
            value={currentValue.value}
          />`
то в функции 
`const getValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
  };`
ничего не выводится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите на свой input внимательно какие там атрибуты вы написали?

```
      <input
        className="Select__value-input"
        readOnly
        onChange={test}
        autoComplete="off"
        value={currentValue.value}
      />
```

1. Как может функция обработать (`onChange`) то что вы ввел пользователь если у него стоит атрибут `readOnly`?
2. Как может функция обработать вообще что нибудь если его присвоили к элементу у который в стилях задано `visibility:hidden; opacity: 0;`

Уберите `readOnly` и эти стили ненужные и все будет работать как надо.И больше не пишите так не логично поставив `readOnly` и `onChange` в `input`.

Рабочая версия `input`-а выглядит так.

```
      <input
        onChange={test}
        autoComplete="off"
        value={currentValue.value}
      />
```

**UPD:**

У вас логика компонента написано не правильно.Поэтому дать правильный ответ тут не просто.
Для того чтобы получить значение из `App` вам надо отправить функцию в компонент и контролировать значение input-а внутри App.И правильно переписать свой код.

Простой пример как это сделать в [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-wood-pb31x?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: у вас в примере функция тест в консоль ничего не выводит. 
и получение значение внутри компонента, это не много не то что я хотел..
мне нужно в `App.js` получить значение из компонента `Select`. Для этого надо передавать функцию как пропс? Или использовать Redux ? и что делать если у меня на странице будет 10 таких кастомных слелектов с разными наборами данных? просто хочу сделать компонент

Comment: @Swartex Я думаю вы не понимаете разницу между `input`-ом и `select`-ом.В `input` функция `onChange` срабатывает только тогда когда что то там вводите.А в `select` если меняете одно значение на другое.В вашем случае у вас `input`.Чтобы увидеть результат в консоли надо поставить фокус и написать что нибудь в экране ничего не будет видно но в консоли отобразится ваш результат.А что касается того чего вы хотели я сейчас дополню свой ответ и покажу как отправить функцию как props.

Comment: Спасибо! и опять это не совсем что мне нужно :) `input` - я использую не просто так ридонли, хотя можно уже и без него обойтись  )) но вы меня натолкнули меня на очень интересную мысль, а именно использовать `useRef()` . Не берусь утверждать что моё решение правильное)

Comment: @Swartex пожалуйста объясните то что вам нужно четко.То что вы хотели сделать я вам объяснил и показал.Но вы не сказали зачем вам и `readOnly` и `onChange` в одном `input`-е хотя утверждаете что это не просто так.У меня нету способности читать ваши мысли если вы их мне не скажите.Удачи :).

Comment: делал как в примере здесь https://ant.design/components/select/
во всех примерах селектов используется `input` c `readonly` ) потому и я также сделал )